# Simple/Starter ANTLR4 program: Exception (AntlrInputStream cannot be cast to CharStream)

Tags: parsing, antlr4, lexer

Issue with type-casting AntlrInputStream to CharStream.  When type-casted, Eclipse is happy (has access to generated code); but runtime - throws exception.  I have marked places of interest between 
///////////////// 
lines.

One area of confusion for me is when I try importing a package/class to resolve a Class, Eclipse finds multiple of them - some in `org.antlr.v4.runtime`; same one is `org.antlr.runtime` and so on.
Some clarity on that will help.  `ANTLR Works developer`(now at Tunnel Vision Labs) did try to shed light on it (very informed; quick to the point answers) - but the use of NetBeans, the use of Antlr-3 to develop part of Antlr 4, and other aspects of the explanation, only added to the confusion...

My apologies for sounding frustrated, but in part, it is fueled by the fact that I **have** used ooolder version of ANTLR more than 8 years back and recollect it as a very pleasant experience - used it to compile SNMP MIBs to create HTML - and worked like a charm.

This time around, facing roadblocks at every corner of this n-degree polygon; n tending to *god-knows-how-many-more*.

Here's the code (grammar verified in ANTLR Works 2.1)

```
    package com.mycompany.devcfg;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;

import org.antlr.runtime.ANTLRInputStream;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.*;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.*;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.Validate;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import com.mycompany.antlr4gencode.VCFGLexer;
import com.mycompany.antlr4gencode.VCFGParser;

public class AntlrMain {

  public static final String DSLFile = "../tpep.dsl";
  public static final String GrammarFile = "../VCFG.g4";
  public static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AntlrMain.class);

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    log.debug ("main.start");

    try {
        log.debug ("try.start");

        InputStream is = new FileInputStream(DSLFile);
        ANTLRInputStream input = new ANTLRInputStream(is);
                    //////////////////////////////////////////
                    // type cast to CharStream is allowed. But exception's thrown anyway.
        VCFGLexer lexer = new VCFGLexer((CharStream) input); 
                    ///////////////////////////////////////////
        Validate.notNull(lexer);
        log.debug("lexer created");

        CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
        VCFGParser parser = new VCFGParser(tokens);
        Validate.notNull(parser);
        log.debug ("parser created");

        /*
        ModuleContext entryPoint = parser.module();
        Validate.notNull(entryPoint);

        ParseTreeWalker walker = new ParseTreeWalker();
        ListenerDelegator listener = new ListenerDelegator();
        walker.walk(listener, entryPoint);
                    log.debug ("walker/listener invoked at 'module');

        */

                    // NOTE: eventually I need the walker.walk (listener, entryPoint)

    } catch (Exception e) {
      Util.throwRuntimeException (e);
    }
    finally {
    log.info ("main.finally.end");
  }
}
```

Trying to replace my company name to 'mycompany' wherever I remembered. It still might creep through:)

The exception (running in Eclipse) in the Command Run Window:

```
        01:10:23,069 DEBUG AntlrMain:27 - main.start
    01:10:23,129 ERROR Util:18 - com.viasat.devcfg.AntlrMain.main(AntlrMain.java:36). 
    Msg: (
      org.antlr.runtime.ANTLRInputStream cannot be cast to org.antlr.v4.runtime.CharStream)
      Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: com.mycompany.devcfg.AntlrMain.main

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
      (AntlrMain.java:36). Msg: (org.antlr.runtime.ANTLRInputStream cannot be cast to
      org.antlr.v4.runtime.CharStream)
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        at com.viasat.devcfg.Util.throwRuntimeException(Util.java:19)
        at com.viasat.devcfg.AntlrMain.main(AntlrMain.java:60)
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're using two different runtimes, and you're trying to cast `ANTLRInputStream` from one runtime to a `CharStream` from another runtime. This can't work as the classes aren't related.

Use only the `v4` runtime (remove `import org.antlr.runtime.ANTLRInputStream;`) and see what happens. Also, make sure to use the v4 runtime jar **from the antlr website** ([here's why](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24468926/3764814)).

Disclaimer: I'm using the .Net version myself so I may be wrong here.

Comment: two runtimes.. that does explain the inability to cast at runtime, but get resolved as far as eclipse goes during development.I made sure of single Jar in the classpath; but will make sure the imports are consistent

Comment: Two classes that have the same name are not the same class. `org.antlr.runtime.ANTLRInputStream` cannot be cast to `org.antlr.runtime.v4.ANTLRInputStream` and therefore neither to `org.antlr.runtime.v4.CharStream`

Comment: Thanks very much!! Your note totally solved my problem =) I was using two different runtimes, but when I removed the first one (leaving only the v4) it worked :D